# ¿Cómo hacer un mapa personalizado de España (incluyendo Canarias) con D3.JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, map, d3.js

Necesito elaborar un mapa de *España* en la que *Canarias*, salga al lado de la península.

Estaba usando *D3.JS* con un mapa de *TopoJSON*, tengo muy poca experiencia con el uso de mapas.

Lo deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me ha ocurrido hacerlo mediante dos *canvas*, y superponer *Canarias* con posicionamiento absoluto, pero creo que es muy mala idea.

Comment: Compañero, te invito a leer la sección de [cómo elaborar una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) en la que entre algunos otros consejos te indica que incluir un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) será de utilidad para que otros puedan ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Ya has conseguido pintar el mapa de españa con d3js y leyendo una fuente topojson, para posicionar las Islas Canaria más arriba, tienes que usar una proyección (seguramente estés usando la GeoMercator).

Esto lo puedes usar la librería d3-composite-projections: https://github.com/rveciana/d3-composite-projections

En código tendrás algo así como (cambiar primera línea por segunda):

```
- const miProyeccion = d3.geoMercator();
+ const miProyeccion = d3Composite.geoConicConformalSpain();
```

Si quieres ver como funciona, aquí tienes un video que lo explica: https://www.lemoncode.tv/curso/d3js-mapa-espana/leccion/proyecciones

Si quieres ver el proceso desde cero de como se pinta un mapa de españa con d3js, aquí tienes la serie de videos completa:https://www.lemoncode.tv/curso/d3js-mapa-espana